How do I remove characters in a list?
The following command when run in BASH cleans The Raven.
cat The_Raven.txt | gawk '{print tolower($0)}' | tr -d "\!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~"

The following command modifies The Raven but makes the file unreadable.
cat The_Raven.txt | gawk '{print tolower($0)}' | tr -d "\!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~«»"

The following Python code uses subprocess to clean "The Raven".
command = "cat The_Raven.txt | gawk '{print tolower($0)}' | tr -d \"!\\\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\\]^_\\`{|}~\""
cleaned_text_from_command = subprocess.run(command, shell = True, capture_output = True, text = True, encoding = 'utf-8').stdout

Inserting «» after ~ in the above Python code causes the following error.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte

How do I remove all relevant characters including «» if they are present?

Don't use encoding='utf-8', since the output is not encoded like that.

BTW, I recommend you use a raw string for command, so you don't need to double all the backslashes.

Why are you doing this with subprocess? Everything you're doing with gawk and tr can be done easily in python itself.

Barmar, I am writing a test that compares cleaned text from a command with cleaned text from a function as asked of me.

I have removed encoding = 'utf-8' per your suggestion with no change. Regarding changing utf-8 to latin-1, latin-1 can't encode all characters in The Raven. Interestingly, the BASH command makes the file unreadable by Python.

You can replace tr ... by sed 's/[CHARLIST]//g' to support UTF-8. Or you can use python functions to do the same.

Your 2nd command does not modify the file in any way. How can it make it unreadable?

Why are you trying to remove that specific list of characters? Are you trying to remove all punctuation characters or something else? In any question you should not provide sample input without the expected output so if you're going to provide a whole book as sample input then you'd provide the "cleaned" whole book as the expected output but don't do that and don't post links or images in questions. Instead, create and post a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, see [ask].

If you're just trying to convert all chars to lower case and remove all punctuation chars that'd be awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,""); print tolower($0)}' in any POSIX awk. If you also want to remove control chars then gsub(/[[:punct:][:cntrl:]]/,""), and if you really need to remove a specific list of chars then gsub(/[]!"#$%&\047()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\^_\{|}~-]/,"")orgsub(/[[:punct:]«»]/,""), etc. What you don't need to do is pipe awkoutput totr`.

Regarding "makes the file unreadable" - [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by that as nothing in your shell commands could make make the input file unreadable, nor could they create an output file that is unreadable unless your umask is set to create files you can't read but I highly doubt that's the case.

Your file starts with a UTF-8 BOM (ef bb bf):
$ od -tx1 -N8 pg17192.txt
0000000 ef bb bf 54 68 65 20 50                                 0000010

The UTF-8 encoding of character » contains a byte (bb) from the BOM:
$ echo '»' | od -tx1
0000000 c2 bb 0a
0000002

The following excerpt from man tr suggests that multi-byte characters might not be supported:

Full support is available only for safe single-byte locales, in which every possible input byte represents a single character.

And a quick test reveals that that is indeed the case; tr -d considers every byte a character and breaks the BOM (bb is missing):
$ tr -d '»' <pg17192.txt | od -tx1 -N8
0000000 ef bf 54 68 65 20 50 72
0000010

This could be avoided by using a tool that supports multi-byte characters:
$ sed 's/»//g' pg17192.txt | od -tx1 -N8
0000000 ef bb bf 54 68 65 20 50
0000010


Also worth noting that tr -d '»' will work with BSD's tr implementation, since it handles UTF-8 characters (as required by POSIX). I'm guessing you are testing with GNU's tr here which does not handle multi-byte characters. Not sure how other tr implementations fare though.

You can do it in python with something like this, filtering out all the non-alphanumeric or spaces from the file and converting to lowercase
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import itertools

with open("pg17192.txt") as file:
    print(''.join((map(str.lower, filter(lambda c: c.isspace() or c.isalnum(), itertools.chain.from_iterable(l for l in file))))))


Some observations -
UUoC. gawk is perfectly capable of reading a file without invoking yet another process which has no purpose other than to feed the data on stdin. Use awk '{yourcode}' file or even awk '{yourcode}' < file (the OS will attach the file on stdin without cat).
By the same token, awk will do all those character suppressions without invoking a separate instance of tr. For a small job like this it's not really a big deal, but it's worth developing the habit of paring away useless bits for when you have a bigger job that requires more efficiency. Practice in the small so you are ready when it's big.
On the flip side of that argument, unless I misjudge, it looks like you are just stripping all the punctuation characters. If that's true, there's an already optimized POSIX character class for that. You probably can get what you want with
awk '{print tolower(gensub(/[[:punct:]]/,"","g")) }' The_Raven.txt

...but if you are already in python, why would you shell out to awk?
import re
with open('The_Raven.txt', encoding="utf-8" ) as file:
  print( re.sub( '[^\s\w]', '', file.read() ) )

